# Change datetime format to Y-m-d, but the datetime is like 7/12/17 6:20:39 pm

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, datetime-format

**EDIT :**

I need to change this datetime into `Y-m-d H:i:s` format from `dd/mm/yy H:i:s` format.

This is for PHP or CodeIgniter project.

---

I got some data from other report not formatted well.

```
datetime
7/12/17 12:15:23 pm (dd/mm/yy H:i:s) format
8/12/17 5:18:12 am
20/12/17 5:12:24 pm
21/12/17 12:17:37 pm
```

If I get example using 1st format date.

```
$example_date = "7/12/17 12:15:23 pm"; // d F Y : 07-December-2017 12:15:23
$format_date = $date("Y-m-d", strtotime($example_date));
```

Its printed : `2007-12-17 12:15:23` It's a wrong result.

In `d F Y` date it's printed `17 December 2007` but It's should be `07 December 2017`.

---

Normally we can change date using like this :

```
$example_datetime = "13/12/2017 12:08:16 pm"; // (dd/mm/yy H:i:s) format
$format_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($example_datetime));
```

> Result from echo `$format_date` => `2017-12-13 12:08:16` is correct. If the year is 2017 and this is what I wanted to.

Comment: _“when I used date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($datetime)); it becomes : 07-12-17 12:15:23”_ - nonsense, that is not even _possible_ with the given format specifier. Plus, https://3v4l.org/jaOGa proves this not to be the case. So, what is the _actual_ issue then? Please edit your question, and include an executable example that shows the problem.

Comment: Hi, that format is (dd/mm/yy). So actually that 7 must be date, 12 must be month or December, 17 must be Year or 2017. That link you gave me, its produce 12 as date and 7 as month.

Comment: So your question is about _parsing_ given date strings using strtotime, and not about outputting them using date.

Comment: I want to ouputing them using date, I'll edit my question.. sorry for confusing.

Comment: question edited. please check.

Comment: This is still not a problem of _outputting_ the data. Naincy tried to explain to you what the issue is already, and Ramraider’s answer shows you how to avoid it, be _telling_ PHP upfront what format your _input_ data is in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `DateTime` and `createFromFormat` method - specifying the format of the input date and then formatting how you wish for output - ex:

```
$example_datetime = "13/12/2017 12:08:16 pm";
$date=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s a', $example_datetime );

$output=$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $output; //  -> 2017-12-13 12:08:16
```

---

For a 2-digit year in the input datestamp, rather than the uppercase `Y` a lowercase `y` should match.

```
$example_datetime = "13/12/17 12:08:16 pm";
$date=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y H:i:s a', $example_datetime );

$output=$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $output; //  -> 2017-12-13 12:08:16
```

Comment: can you try to use : `13/12/17 12:08:16 pm` for the output ? thank you.

Comment: `Result that I need => 2017-12-13 12:08:16` ?? is the output from above - as expected so I don't understand your comment

Comment: edited question. please check again. thank you.

Comment: @zinc if you want to parse a date with a 2-digit year instead of a 4-digit one, then you need to replace the part that specifies the year in the format string accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe I will try it again, thank you for your help. I was found that correct answer from RamRaider. I edited his answer. After approved I'll make it correct.

Comment: Note that DateTime::createFromFormat returns FALSE on error. You can fetch the errors with DateTime::getLastErrors()

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$example_datetime = "13/12/2017 12:08:16 pm"; // (dd/mm/yy H:i:s) format
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $example_datetime);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date)); // Y-m-d H:i:s
```

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguate by looking at the
>   separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash
>   (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a
>   dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>   Check more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Hi Naincy, thank you for your help. But can you try to use `13/12/17 12:08:16 pm` for the date

Comment: question edited. please check