# Date convert showing wrongly

Tags: php, date, date-format

I like to convert a date format **dd/mm/yyyy** to another format in PHP.

My Code:

```
$date = '29/01/2018';
echo date('l jS F Y', strtotime($date));
```

When I run the above code, it's showing me some wrong date:

```
Thursday 1st January 1970
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: strtotime  unsertands it as mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: this happen because your $date have unknown format for strtotime

Comment: Same problem as in this other recent question, same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48517562/1427878

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the DateTime objects to help you converting dates. You can "create a datetime object from an specified format" and convert it.

```
$date = "29/01/2018";
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $date);

echo $dt->format("l jS F Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

signifies American M/D/Y formatting

```
<?php

$date = '01/29/2018';
echo date('l jS F Y', strtotime($date));
```

output

```
Monday 29th January 2018
```